# The proof of general strong law of large numbers

Tags: uniform-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let the function $f\colon \mathbb R^n \times \Xi \to \mathbb R$ be measurable, $f(\cdot, \xi)$ for $\xi$ fixed be lower semicontinuous. Supose that there exists an $\mathbf P$-integrable ($\mathbf P$ is a probabilistic measure) function $a(\xi)$ such that $$f(x, \xi) \ge a(\xi)$$ holds true for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$. Let $$F_n(x,\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n) = \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n f(x, \xi_k).$$ Let $\{x_i\}$ be a sequence such that $$\lim_{i\to\infty} x_i = x_0.$$
It is known (the standard stong law of large numbers) that for all $i\in\mathbb N$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(x_i,\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n) = (Ef)(x_i)$$ for all sequences $\{\xi_n\}\in \Theta$, where $\Theta$ is a set of full measure, $E$ is the expectation. Let a sequence $\{\xi_n\}\in \Theta$ be fixed. Also, we suppose that $$(Ef)(x_i)\to (Ef)(x_0).$$
Is this true that there exists a subsequnce, say $\{y_n\}$, of $\{x_n\}$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(y_n,\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n) = (Ef)(x_0)?$$ 
The authors of the paper [Artstein Z., Wets R.J.-B. Consistency of minimizers and the SLLN for stochastic programs // Journal of Convex Analysis. 1996. V. 2. P. 1-17.] write that this is clear, but I don't understand this. One of the convergences should be uniform, and this is not obvious. This property is used to prove the general strong law of large numbers for stochastic programs.

Comment: I'm not sure, it seems they used the diagonal argument?

Comment: Not necessary, because $y_n$ can be a subsequence of the sequence $x_n$